# Minecraft Forge wont let me play mods

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I have installed the recommended version of forge and I have installed a mod but it still wont let me play and I've been told to go into my mods folder but I don't have one

Answer (score 0):

You have to run minecraft in your forge profile once without mods. Then, the mods folder will appear. If the mod comes in a .zip or a .jar, just put it in the mods folder. If it is something else, try looking at the download page for instructions on how to install it.